# Instantiating a given set of classes with parameterized constructors

Tags: java, reflection

Is it possible in Java to take a collection of classes with parameterized constructors and instantiate each one of them at run time? These classes have only one constructor that can take any number of primitive type arguments, though the number of arguments they take can vary for each class. As an example, here are four classes that we want to instantiate at run time:

```
 public class One { public One(int a) { } }
 public class Two { public Two(char a, int b) { } }
 public class Three { public Three(float a, char b, int c) { } }
 public class Four { public Four(float a, char b, int c) { } }
```

Comment: With reflection, you can find the constructor (as there's only one), but where would the `a`, `b`, `c` etc values come from?

Comment: @RC i'm not sure. it seems that even when we use Constructor.newInstance(), we still need to know the number and order of arguments during compile time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Class oneC = Class.forName("One"); // use FQCN
Contructor constructor = oncC.getConstructors()[0]; // assuming that the class has only 1 constructor
Class<?>[] paramTypes = constructor.getParameterTypes();
// Iterate paramTypes, create each parameter value and then call constructor.newInstance(...)
```

Reference:

- [Constructor#getParameterTypes()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html#getParameterTypes%28%29)
- [Class#getConstructors()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructors%28%29)